# Sphere falling in viscous fluid boundary condition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

A sphere, radius $a$, falls at constant velocity $U_0$ through an incompressible
viscous fluid. I am told to assume that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u} = U_0\mathbf{e}_z + \tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})=\nabla\times\nabla\times(U_0f(r)\mathbf{e}_z).
\end{equation}
From this I have shown that
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})=-U_0\Delta f \mathbf{e}_z
\end{equation}
and by taking the curl of the equations for Stokes flow,
\begin{equation}
\Delta^2 f= \text{ constant.}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta^2 f=\Delta(\Delta f)$. I also know that
\begin{equation}
\Delta f\rightarrow0 \text{ as } r\rightarrow\infty.
\end{equation}
**Here is where I am confused**

I need to show that $f(r)=Ar+\frac{B}{r}$. I tried to do so by the Ansatz $f=r^a$ and found that $a=-1,0,1,2,4$ are all suitable for $\Delta^2 f=$ constant to hold. So $f(r)=Ar+\frac{B}{r}+C+Dr^2+Er^4.$ To satisfy $\Delta f\rightarrow0 \text{ as } r\rightarrow\infty$, I set $D=E=0$.

But I cannot explain why $C=0$. Why is this true?

**I also don't know how to set $A,B$**

I think that $\textbf{u}=U_0\textbf{e}_z \text{ at } r=a$ for the no-slip condition, which sets $\tilde{\textbf{u}}=-U_0\Delta f\textbf{e}_z=0 \text{ at } r=a \implies A=0$.

So now I have $f(r)=\frac{B}{r}$, and somehow I have to use the fact that $\nabla\times\textbf{e}_\phi=\frac{cot\theta}{r}\textbf{e}_r-\frac{1}{r}\textbf{e}_\theta$ to find $B$. I am completely lost here.

Comment: I also got confused by this (not my notation - the problem is written this way). I have edited the question to show that this notation is for the 'Laplacian of the Laplacian'. Do I have it right that $\tilde{u}=0$ at $r=a$? As for the velocity approaching the mean steady flow at infinity, this is just the $\Delta f \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$ condition, correct? But in that case, $B$ can still be arbitrary?

Comment: @EditPiAf now I am more confused. If $f(r)=\frac{B}{r}$ is the correct solution then $\tilde{u}=0$ everywhere, surely this isn't correct?

Comment: @AzamatBagatov:  This is not potential flow with zero normal boundary conditions at the sphere -- as commented above.  This is Stokes flow (as you say) with no-slip at the surface.

Comment: @RRL Sorry but I still don't understand - what would the boundary condition be in that case?

Comment: Your steps to arrive at the general solution  (when done correctly) should produce the general solution (3) shown below for the disturbance velocity field. I have then shown you how to apply the correct boundary conditions -- arriving at the very well-known solution for Stokes flow past a sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free-stream and boundary conditions are $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) \to U_0\mathbf{e}_z = U_0\cos \theta \,\mathbf{e}_r - U_0 \sin \theta \,\mathbf{e}_\theta $ as $r \to \infty$ and $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) =\mathbf{0}$ at $r = a$. For axisymmetric flow the disturbance velocity  $\tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})$ has non-zero components $\tilde{u}_r$ and $\tilde{u}_\theta$ in the radial and angular directions and the free-stream and boundary conditions reduce to

$$\tag{1} \tilde{u}_r \to 0, \,\, \tilde{u}_\theta \to 0 \,\, \text{ as } \,\, r \to \infty$$

$$\tag{2}\tilde{u}_r = -U_0\cos\theta,\,\, \tilde{u}_\theta = U_0\sin \theta \,\, \text{ at } \,\, r = a$$

This problem can be framed in terms of a streamfunction $\psi$ such that

$$\tilde{u}_r = \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta}, \,\, \tilde{u}_\theta = \frac{-1}{r \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$$

Similar to your approach, the streamfunction can be shown to have the general solution

$$\psi = \left(\frac{A}{r} + Br + Cr^2 + Dr^4\right) \sin^2 \theta,$$

whence

$$\tag{3}\tilde{u}_r = \frac{2 \cos \theta}{r^2}\left(\frac{A}{r} + Br + Cr^2 + Dr^4\right), \\ \tilde{u}_\theta = \frac{- \sin \theta}{r}\left(-\frac{A}{r^2} + B + 2Cr + 4Dr^3\right)$$

Applying condition (1) we get $C= D = 0$.  Applying condition (2) we get

$$\left.\tilde{u}_r\right|_{r = a} = 2 \cos \theta\left(\frac{A}{a^3} + \frac{B}{a} \right) = - U_0 \cos \theta, \\ \left.\tilde{u}_\theta\right|_{r = a} = -\sin \theta\left(-\frac{A}{a^3} + \frac{B}{a} \right) =  U_0 \sin \theta$$

Solving, we get  $A= \frac{U_0a^3}{4}$ and $B= \frac{-3U_0a}{4}$ and

$$\tilde{u}_r = U_0 \cos\theta \left(\frac{ a^3}{2r^3} - \frac{3a}{2r}\right), \,\,\tilde{u}_\theta = -U_0 \sin\theta \left(-\frac{ a^3}{4r^3} - \frac{3a}{4r}\right)$$

---

**Linking Approaches**

Starting with the ansatz $\tilde{\mathbf{u}}=\nabla\times\nabla\times(U_0f(r)\mathbf{e}_z)$, we have

$$\nabla\times(U_0f(r)\mathbf{e}_z) = -U_0\sin \theta \frac{df}{dr} \mathbf{e}_\phi,$$

and

$$\tag{4}\tilde{\mathbf{u}} = \nabla \times \left( -U_0\sin \theta \frac{df}{dr} \mathbf{e}_\phi\right) = \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(- U_0\sin^2 \theta \frac{df}{dr} \right)\mathbf{e}_r - \frac{1}{r } \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(- U_0r\sin \theta \frac{df}{dr} \right)\mathbf{e}_\theta \\ = \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\underbrace{- U_0\sin^2 \theta \,r\frac{df}{dr}}_{\psi} \right)\mathbf{e}_r - \frac{1}{r \sin \theta } \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\underbrace{- U_0\sin^2 \theta \,r\frac{df}{dr}}_{\psi} \right)\mathbf{e}_\theta$$

(Here you see the appearance of the streamfunction $\psi$).  Taking the curl of the Stokes equations and some additional steps it can be shown that the problem reduces to

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\sin \theta}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left( \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right) \right)^2 \left(U_0 \sin^2 \theta \, r \frac{df}{dr} \right) =0,$$

and with further simplification to

$$\left(\frac{d^2}{d r^2} - \frac{2}{r^2} \right)^2 \left( r \frac{df}{dr} \right) =0$$

This admits the general solution

$$r \frac{df}{dr} = \frac{A}{r} + Br + Cr^2 + Dr^4$$

Substituting into (4), solving for the components $\tilde{u}_r$ and $\tilde{u}_\theta$, and applying the boundary conditions as before gives the solution for Stokes flow past a sphere.

Comment: How am I meant to know from the start that all of this can be solved by a streamfunction $\psi$ satisfying $\tilde{u}_r = \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta}, \,\, \tilde{u}_\theta = \frac{-1}{r \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$.

I am not told this at the start of the problem so how am I supposed to come up with it? Especially since it doesn't match the $\Delta ^2 f=$constant condition.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but when switching from $\mathbf{e}_z$ to spherical co-ordinates is it not true that $\mathbf{e}_z=\cos\theta\mathbf{e_r}-\sin\theta\mathbf{e_\phi}$ and not $\mathbf{e}_z=\cos\theta\mathbf{e_r}-\sin\theta\mathbf{e_\theta}$, so that

$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) \to U_0\mathbf{e}_z = U_0\cos \theta \,\mathbf{e}_r - U_0 \sin \theta \,\mathbf{e}_\phi$

Comment: @AzamatBagatov:  With $\theta$ as the polar angle and $\phi$ as the azimuthal angle you should have $\mathbf{e}_z = \cos \theta \mathbf{e}_r - \sin \theta \mathbf{e}_\theta$. Whatever convention you use, the expression for $\mathbf{e}_z$ should only involve one angle -- the polar angle.  That is obvious from axisymmetry.

Comment: See section on vector fields in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates, relating spherical unit vectors to Cartesian unit vectors.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I am still confused about what I mentioned in my first comment however.

Comment: As for the first question -- you wouldn't know about $\psi$ unless you did some research on the general topic of Stokes flow where it is a commonly used and powerful technique.  The problem you have is trying to following a recipe you are being given in an unnamed source and I think you are making mistakes along the way.  The point to my answer is -- whatever you are doing, you should arrive at a form for the velocity similar to mine and then apply the conditions I gave you.  I would have to work through your approach carefully to see why you can't arrive at a useful general solution.

Comment: I believe the first mistake you made is getting $\tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})=-U_0\Delta f \mathbf{e}_z$.  This means $\tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})=-U_0\Delta f (\cos \theta \mathbf{e}_r - \sin \theta \mathbf{e}_\theta)$ and $\tilde{u}_r = - U_0 \cos \theta \Delta f, \,\, \tilde{u}_\theta = U_0 \sin \theta \Delta f$.  This is not correct as the two components are showing the same functional dependence on $r$.  See my solution which I know as the correct Stokes solution.

Comment: @AzamatBagatov: I've added more to show how you can salvage your approach.